# SQL Compact Edition - Access to the database file is not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am in the process of creating a blog site from scratch using MVC 3.0 and the Entity Framework.  I am using a SQL CE .sdf file for the data store.  This is stored in the projects App_Data folder.  Locally, everything works fine.  Not a problem.  The .sdf file is read and processed without error.  However, after using Web Deploy to publish to a shared hosting provider, I get the following error when trying to view the remote site:-

Access to the database file is not allowed

The connection string I am using in web config is:-

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataAccess.BlogDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=DansMVCBlog.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have researched the problem and have hit a brick wall.  Suggestions have included adding App_Data/DansMVCBlog.sdf to the connection string file path rather than just the file name.  This does not work as you are advised the file path is invalid.  On the shared hosting control panel, I have set read/write permissions on the App_Data folder to be true.  Also, in my Global.asax file, I have disabled 
`Database.SetInitializer(new DataInitializer());

Am I making a schoolboy error here?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who knows what the solution to this was. All I can say is I was having problems publishing using web deploy, so I switched to using ftp. After that everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the OP may have solved their problem but in my case, it turned out that the database file had been marked as Read Only by my source control system.  Clearing the Read Only flag solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update your connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DataAccess.BlogDbContext" 
       connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|DansMVCBlog.sdf"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks but i'v tried that.  The only different thing I can see in your connection string example is the inclusion of |DataDirectory| which Iv explained doesn't work.  Also, I have manually updated the web config conn string via the shared hosting control panel but not joy.

Comment: Normally hosts don't provide read and Write access to the AppData directory, and either you or support has to manually provide the WebSite appPool Identity R/W access to the folder.

Comment: You may want to try turning off ACL on webdeploy `<IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>`.